# Converting textarea newlines into <p> and <br/> tags by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, newline, string-formatting

I'm using a textarea in an html form and I'm trying to reformat its content into a valid html format by using `<p>` and `<br/>` tags.

I wrote this script and it seems to work but I wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything. So I'm asking for feedback. I'm aware that I'm not taking into consideration the possibility that the user might explicitly input html tags, but that's no problem because I'll be issuing the result in PHP anyway.

Thanks in advance.

#### An example to the output:

```
<p>Line 1<br/>Line 2</p><p>Line 4<br/><br/><br/>Line 7</p>
```

#### and the code:

```js
function getHTML() {

    var v = document.forms[0]['txtArea'].value;
    v = v.replace(/\r?\n/gm, '<br/>');
    v = v.replace(/(?!<br\/>)(.{5})<br\/><br\/>(?!<br\/>)/gi, '$1</p><p>');
    if (v.indexOf("<p>") > v.indexOf("</p>")) v = "<p>" + v;
    if (v.lastIndexOf("</p>") < v.lastIndexOf("<p>")) v += "</p>";
    if (v.length > 1 && v.indexOf("<p>") == -1) v = "<p>" + v + "</p>";
    alert(v);

}
```

Please note that this is a code meant to be part of a CMS and all I care to do by JavaScript is to rebuild the textarea result with those 2 tags. Kind of WYSIWYG issue...

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: What exactly is the relevance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.

```
function encode4HTML(str) {
    return str
        .replace(/\r\n?/g,'\n')
        // normalize newlines - I'm not sure how these
        // are parsed in PC's. In Mac's they're \n's
        .replace(/(^((?!\n)\s)+|((?!\n)\s)+$)/gm,'')
        // trim each line
        .replace(/(?!\n)\s+/g,' ')
        // reduce multiple spaces to 2 (like in "a    b")
        .replace(/^\n+|\n+$/g,'')
        // trim the whole string
        .replace(/[<>&"']/g,function(a) {
        // replace these signs with encoded versions
            switch (a) {
                case '<'    : return '&lt;';
                case '>'    : return '&gt;';
                case '&'    : return '&amp;';
                case '"'    : return '&quot;';
                case '\''   : return '&apos;';
            }
        })
        .replace(/\n{2,}/g,'</p><p>')
        // replace 2 or more consecutive empty lines with these
        .replace(/\n/g,'<br />')
        // replace single newline symbols with the <br /> entity
        .replace(/^(.+?)$/,'<p>$1</p>');
        // wrap all the string into <p> tags
        // if there's at least 1 non-empty character
}
```

All you need to do is call this function with the value of the textarea.

```
var ta = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
console.log(encode4HTML(ta.value));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v = v.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
    .replace(/([^\r\n]+)\r?\n\r?\n/g, "<p>$1</p>")
    .replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br />");
```

Comment: Thanks but this formatting creates a different result. I'm into creating a WYSIWYG kind of area.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What is not WYSIWYG about this?

Comment: The result. Try it with a textarea to see the result. Newlines are visuallyb different than those of the textarea.

Answer (score -1):

Omg, you are trying to pass html code to the backend? That is what we call a XSS hole.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

How about ubb code instead?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBB.threads

Comment: That is not meant to be a public page. Only a CMS page I'm scripting.

Comment: It's perfectly okay to send HTML to the backend, publicly or privately. How do you think some comment boxes and forum thread editors send formatted HTML posts to a backend database?! It's passing HTML to the front end you should be worried about! As long as you thoroughly validate the HTML before using it, with something like http://www.htmlpurifier.org or some of PHP's built in functions (depending on requirements), then it's deemed relatively safe, for now. You could validate the HTML string before saving it to the database if you're that concerned.